# Gradle not more detail for ':compileKotlin'

Tags: gradle, kotlinc

I'm new on gradle and kotlin

When i build **syntax error** file using `gradle build`
it's just show

```
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

How do i get which line syntax error like using `kotlinc`?

PS: using vscode, so i need it

---

edited

Sorry, i missed up error message because difference between `gradle` and `kotlinc`

gradle:

```
PS C:\PlayGround2> gradle build
e: C:\PlayGround2\src\main\kotlin\Main.kt: (26, 1): Expecting a top level declaration

> Task :compileKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation
...
```

kotlinc:

```
PS C:\PlayGround2\src\main\kotlin> kotlinc .\Main.kt
Main.kt:26:1: error: expecting a top level declaration
}       <--- this line not shown in kotlinc
```

Answer (score 0):

that's a known issue, someone has solved it by uninstalling all java versions and only install JDK 8.

edit: also check this link : https://github.com/waicool20/KAGA/issues/27

Have a nice day.